# Service Oriented Architecture and the UI

Tags: api, user-interface, service, soa

So, I am building a new system and thinking I need to get with the times and use SoA. I have my website, and then there are services and systems around that that help the website work, lets take a localization service as an example.

This has it's services and an API that allows you to make an HTTP call to get texts in a specific language, that works great, it's just AJAX.

What about though if in the website's Admin section we want to expose a UI to the Localization service to allow the editing/creating etc of a new text. Should the Localization service in it's silo have a UI that the website can then "inject" into it's interface, or is the website a "UI Service" that then solely calls the Localization service's API?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SOA your aim is to create an inventory of reusable, agnostic, standardised services. These services become enterprise assets - they reduce time to market by providing flexibility and end up being a competitive advantage for the enterprise.

In a SOA services are available for consumption via Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) or some other type of middleware that enables easy transformations between services, enables orchestration, provides an additional layer between providers and consumers, etc. An important point is that web services should be designed to expose reusable functionality as much as possible.

If you embed/inject the UI directly, you'll introduce at least three problems (and there are more, these are just the ones that come off the top of my head at the moment) :

1. The service you create **will not be reusable** in all scenarios, because it doesn't fully leverage the established standards like SOAP or REST - imagine you have to embed it in a windows forms application in the future - you won't be able to do this easily.
2. **UI presentation of data must be a concern of the consuming application** - otherwise you're not having a clear separation of concerns - which can introduce a number of problems in the future. Moreover you're not giving the freedom of choice to the consumer.
3. You do **point-to-point integration** that will couple applications to each other. Such integration tends to result in messy architectures that become a nightmare to maintain.

I hope this helps you. I'll recommend reading [a book on the subject](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529550.do) in order to make sure you do things properly.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for the excellent response. I will definitely get a book or three and make sure my services are just business areas keeping them agnostic.